# Error when using dllexport?

Tags: c++, .net, managed-c++, dllexport

I want to export the functions by using dllexport. But I encountered the error while compiler "error C4439: 'WrappedC' : function definition with a managed type in the signature must have a __clrcall calling convention".

My code in header file (.h) is:

```
extern "C" 
{

__declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall ABC(int i);
__declspec(dllexport) char* __stdcall C(int i);
__declspec(dllexport) array<char>^ __stdcall WrappedC(int i) ;

}
```

I have tried to change _stdcall to __clrcall but it make another error:

```
error C3395: 'WrappedC' : __declspec(dllexport) cannot be applied to a function with the __clrcall calling convention
```

I have searched on internet but i have not solved it yet.

Thanks,

T&TGroup

Answer (score 2):

The compiler has already pretty much told you what the problem is.

```
__declspec(dllexport) array<char>^ __stdcall WrappedC(int i)
```

You cannot use `__declspec(dllexport)` due to the fact that that function is using `clr`.

`array<char>^` is pretty much the part it is complaining about as it's not native code.

Comment: Whoops! i knew i forgot something. You can declare the function as public but you cant use it in an unmanaged program.

Comment: @Aleks: I want to export the function with the return type is a managed type, Can you give me a little code sample? This is the first time I work with dllexport, so I'm pretty stupid ^^. Many thanks!

Comment: well actually I believe this may be relevant if not the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546425/export-function-with-clr-parameters-from-dll it is basically as I said, get rid of __declspec and __stdcall and chuck a public: at the beginning.

Comment: Maybe this article could shed some light http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6242/Step-by-Step-Calling-C-DLLs-from-VC-and-VB-Part-1